# Windows-like Qt4 Menubar in Mac Os X

Tags: macos, qt4, menubar

I would like my application to look similar to that of the Windows version: instead of the menu being displaced to the top menu in Os X, I'd like my program to have the file menu right on top of the application itself.

I've looked at the Qt documentation regarding this, but I can't seem to create an empty QMenuBar as the top level QMenuBar. (I'm using a subclass of QMainWindow...)

Comment: You are going to piss off your mac users if it behaves like a windows app.

Comment: If you fullscreen your app, what happens to the menu bar?

Comment: As you can see, Mac users are pretty adamant that they probably don't want you to do this. Perhaps you can give us some more info about *why* you want to have an in-window menu bar?

Comment: +1 to make readers to realize why they should follow Apple's UI guideline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bad idea and will not win your application fans in the Mac community. [Here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGIntro/XHIGIntro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000894-TP6) are the Apple Human Interface Guidelines.

Answer (score 5):

Why would he want to do this?  Multiple Monitors, that's why.  Complete pain in the keester to have to move your mouse from the monitor you are working in back to the main monitor to access the menu bar and then all the way back over to the monitor you were in. I think it would be FANTASTIC if more mac apps at least had the option to place their menu directly in the application window.

Comment: Even in the same monitor, if I'm switching between two windows and I need to access their menu bars, it's a strange mouse dance.

Comment: You should learn more about UI/UX on Mac OS X platform. Especially **why** the people like to pay a lot more than Windows.

Comment: [From wikipedia] Mac made this choice in the 80`s and did not change since (while screen did). This was probably for the same reason as most of the other un-standard stuff such as the 1 button mouse, keyboard layout, etc... Hopefully, the era of advanced haptic devices will free us from this curse.

Answer (score 2):

The first menubar you create becomes the main mac menubar. You could try creating a dummy one immediately after you create the QApplication.  You might want to put at least a quit command in there.

Alternatively, you can call `QApplication::setAttribute` with `Qt::AA_DontUseNativeMenuBar`. I don't know what will fill the mac menubar in that case, however.